# dc.js Stretch GeoChoroplethChart to Full Screen

Tags: javascript, d3.js, choropleth

I'm trying to create a world map using d3.geoChoroplethChart. My problem is that I can't stretch it to the full screen. I'm setting the width of the chart, and svg is picking up the setting, but the underlying g element does not. I assume it uses the projection together with the set width to calculate its size.

The projection I'm using

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([0, 55])
            .scale(180);
```

Here is chart code

```
mapChart.width(2000)
                .height(1000)
                .dimension(countryDim)
                .group(countryDimGroup)
                .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
                .projection(projection)
                .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value; })
                .overlayGeoJson(africaJson.features, "Countries", function(d) {
                    return d.properties.admin.toUpperCase();
                });
```

I use geoJSON from here http://geojson-maps.kyd.com.au/

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try changing the value you used for the scale?

Comment: Yes, but the countries do not fit into the chart if I go too high.